# How can I simplify this proposition where 4 out of 5 values are true and the remaining 1 out of 5 is false?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am fairly new to logic and I am curious as to whether it is possible to simplify this proposition where 4 out of 5 values must be true and one of them has to be false.

(P1 ∧ P2 ∧ P3 ∧ P4 ∧ ¬P5) ∨ (P1 ∧ P2 ∧ P3 ∧ ¬P4 ∧ P5) ∨ (P1 ∧ P2 ∧ ¬P3 ∧ P4 ∧ P5) ∨ (P1 ∧ ¬P2 ∧ P3 ∧ P4 ∧ P5) ∨ (¬P1 ∧ P2 ∧ P3 ∧ P4 ∧ P5)

As you can see my current proposition is unnecessarily long.

Comment: The statement may not be in its shortest form, but it is definitely easiest to understand like that. But if you want it shorter, you can use the distributive property to combine some terms. For example $(P_1 \wedge P_2 \wedge P_3 \wedge P_4 \wedge \lnot P_5) \vee (P_1 \wedge P_2 \wedge P_3 \wedge \lnot P_4 \wedge P_5)$ can be rewritten as $P_1 \wedge P_2 \wedge P_3 \wedge ((P_4 \wedge \lnot P_5) \vee (\lnot P_4 \wedge P_5))$.

Comment: can we use the xor operator ?

Comment: @Magma Thank you, this helps a lot